# how to count the occurrence of the property in list of object

Tags: c#, list, object

I have 2 list of objects

```
   List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 


      new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "Android"},
      new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "Android"}
      new Student(){ StudentName="Steve",MobileOS = "IOS"},
      new Student(){ StudentName="Ram",  MobileOS = "IOS"},
      new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "IOS"}
}
```

In my other list, I want to store filtered data. Example

```
    List<FilteredData> filteredData= new List<FilteredData>(){

          new FilteredData(){ StudentName="Bill", Count=3, Android = 2, Ios = 1},
          new FilteredData(){ StudentName="Steve",Count=1, Android = 0, Ios = 1},
          new FilteredData(){ StudentName="Ram",  Count=1, Android = 0, Ios = 1},
}
```

**Noted:** the **Count** value is based on the occurrence of same **StudentName**
 and the number of **Android** and **Ios** is based on **MobileOS**

So, how can I count the same Student name and store it into a new list?
I searched whole day but seems can't found a solution for this

Comment: Sounds to me like you're basically searching for something like the [GroupBy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)... Have you tried that already? Also, could you please add your current (non-working) attempt at this to your question?

Comment: How dynamic do you need it to be? Are there only two choices for `MobileOS`? And do you need hard properties or could you have a `Dictionary<string, int>` to represent the os and counts?

Answer (score 2):

Using linq you could reduce it to

```
var filteredData =
    studentList
        .GroupBy(item => item.StudentName)
        .Select(group => new FilteredData 
        {
            StudentID = group.First().StudentID, 
            StudentName = group.Key, 
            Count = group.Count() 
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: hi Jannik, thanks for your answer, I posted wrong code last night, I have updated the question,can you please take a look on that?

Comment: you could use  

`.Select(group => new FilteredData
{
    StudentName = group.Key,
    Count = group.Count(),
    Android = group.Where(item => item.MobileOS == "Android"),
    Ios = group.Where(item => item.MobileOS == "IOS")
})`

Answer (score 1):

```
var filtereddata = studentList
    .GroupBy(x => x.SudentID)
    .Select(x => new FilteredData() { 
         StudentID = x.Key, 
         StudentName = x.First().StudentName, 
         Count = x.Count(),
         Android = x.Count(y => y.MobileOS == "Android"),
         Ios = x.Count(y => y.MobileOS == "IOS")
    });
```

Comment: hi Martin,  thanks for your answer, I posted wrong code last night, I have updated the question,can you please take a look on that?